# URL for local files on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, cookies

Hi I'm trying to read cookie on windows mobile using     `InternetGetCookie`    , and the cookie is set by a local html file, so how does the URL for a local file look like?

something like `file:///\\Storage%20Card`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question is yes.